# How to produce an array from an object where the number of elements is determined by Object.values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an object like so:

```
{ green: 2, blue: 1, red: 2}
```

How can I turn it into an array that looks like this:

```
[ 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'red']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be done like this:

```
Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([k, v]) => Array(v).fill(k));
```

Example:

```js
const obj = { green: 2, blue: 1, red: 2};
const res = Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([k, v]) => Array(v).fill(k));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!
Just for my education - I guess I should read Array(v).fill(k) as: make 2 arrays and fill them with value 'green' // which then results in 1st and 2nd element "green" 
and so on...
Am I reading it right?

Comment: Yes, per color you get such little arrays of repeating values, which are then combined to one  array with flatMap.

Answer (score 1):

This is a neat way with a generator. Perhaps a little overkill for this example.

```js
function* makeIterator(obj) {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (const key of keys) {
        const value = obj[key];
        for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
            yield key;
        }
    }
}

const obj = {green: 2, blue: 1, red: 2};
console.log(Array.from(makeIterator(obj)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` with `Object.entries`:

```js
const obj = { green: 2, blue: 1, red: 2};
const res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a.push(...new Array(v).fill(k)), a), []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.entries will do that - it gives a key: value pair of each property in the object. You then use the value to push the key into an array that gives you the desired output.

```js
var obj = { green: 2, blue: 1, red: 2};

var newArr = [];
var objEntries = Object.entries(obj);

objEntries.forEach(function(item){
  for(var i = 0; i < item[1]; i++){
   newArr.push(item[0])
  };
})

console.log(newArr); // gives //[ 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'red']
```

Comment: I voted for a somewhat simpler solution above, but yours is very smart as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var data={ green: 2, blue: 1, red: 2};
var newData=[];
for(let i in data){
    for(let j=0;j<data[i];j++){
        newData.push(i);
    }
}
console.log('newData = ', newData);
```

output

```
newData = ["green", "green", "blue", "red", "red"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you do not want to deal with polifills for [flatMap support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility) in IE etc you can also consider this solution which is based only on [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
let obj = {green: 2, blue: 1, red: 2}, arr=[]

Object.keys(obj).forEach(x => arr.push(...Array(obj[x]).fill(x)))

console.log(arr)
```

Another approach you can take to avoid ES6 Array destructuring is via [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
let obj = {green: 2, blue: 1, red: 2}

let r = Object.entries(obj).reduce((r,[k,v]) => r.concat(Array(v).fill(k)),[])

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map and flat if you don't want to use flatMap directly

```
const obj = { 
   green: 2, 
   blue: 1, 
   red: 2
};

const responseArray = Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key,value]) => {
        return Array(value).fill(key)
}).flat();

console.log(responseArray);
//  ["green", "green", "blue", "red", "red"]
```